# Java regex to find +(plus sign) with characters

Tags: java, regex, string

With java regex i want to find the word "C++" and it should not be positive with only "C".

The below code should explain the rest, see [here](https://jdoodle.com/ia/zvQ)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  String test = "Framework, c++ and Visual Studio IDEs.";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\+\\+\\b.*");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Pattern1 True");
    }
  p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\Bc.+.+\\B.*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.print("Pattern2 True");
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc+$\\b.*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Pattern3 is True but how to return false");
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\Bc\\B.*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Pattern4 is True");
    }
  if(test.toLowerCase()   .contains("c++")) {
        System.out.print("Contains c++ True");
  }
  if(test.toLowerCase().contains("C")) {
        System.out.print("Contains C True");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Use a non-word boundary, `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\+\\+\\B.*");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nice one with C++, will this work with only "C"

Comment: If you want to match `C` not followed with `++`, use `\bC\b(?!\+\+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew     (?i).*\\bC\\b(?!\\+\\+).*

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\+\\+\\B.*");     // C++
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bC\\b(?!\\+{2}).*"); // C only
```

Here,

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `c\+\+` - a `c++` string
- `\B` - a non-word boundary, on the right, there must be end of string or a non-word char
- `(?!\+{2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `++` string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: for omitting all appending characters with C - "(?i).*\\bC\\b(?!\\+|#|\\$|\\*|\\^|%|&).*" Phew is there is anyway to do a asterisk with those omitting characters, can we propose the regex community to do so?

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya You need to make sure what your "word" boundary is like. If you can describe it using a finite amount of special chars, then the above pattern is a solution.  If you can describe it in any other way, please do and we'll be able to adjust the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work at detecting either "C++" or "c++" anywhere in an input string.

```java
String regex = ".*[cC]\\+\\+.*";
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "This is NOT c++ !");
```

Results in `true`, but

```java
java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(regex, "This is NOT c!");
```

results in `false`.

Comment: how to find only c and false for c++

Answer (score 0):

tough time omitting characters for only C

```
p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bC\\b(?!\\+|#|\\$|\\*|\\^|%|&|\\.).*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("C is true");
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\+\\+\\B.*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("C++ is true");
    }
    p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*\\bc\\#\\B.*");
  m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("C# is true");
    }
```